# Stop video recording by pressing Home button

Tags: ios, avfoundation

How do I safely stop video recording on AVFramework, when home button is pressed?

I want my app to work like the native camera app: when you press the home button during recording it stops the recording process and then goes to the background mode.

On my app delegate, I call `[[videoController captureManager] stopRecording];` but in `recordingDidFinishToOutputFileURL` I get an error which says:

> Stop any other actions using the recording device and try again.

Comment: I understand you want it to feel like it's the same as on the native camera app, but doesn't it make more sense to stop recording when you press the `End` button?

Comment: but what if you have an incoming call during video recording? in that case app goes to the background and throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the call to stop your video recording in your app delegate's `applicationWillResignActive:` method. This method is triggered when your app moves from being active to being inactive, which, according to the [UIApplicationDelegate docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW9), occurs:

> ... for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.

The code would look something like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[videoController captureManager] stopRecording];

    // Do anything else before app becomes inactive
}
```

Comment: this solution is better than mine, but sometimes i still getting exception

Comment: By the way, [[videoController captureManager] stopRecording] does not prevent app to go background mode. app enters to background  mode and then after that stoprecording is faired.

Comment: That's the reason you might still be getting an exception, as it's possible that there's not enough time for the `stopRecording` method to do its job before the app is put into the background.

Comment: but after pressing home button app goes to the background immediately.
From Apple docs i have read that applicationDidEnterBackground: method must still exit within 5 seconds. i think this 5 sec will be enough to do job

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is happening behind the scenes, as you're at the mercy of Apple's system for putting apps into the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try recovering recorded video...

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
    {
        BOOL recordedSuccessfully = NO;
        if ([error code] != noErr)
        {
            if(outputFileURL)
            {
                NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSString* path = outputFileURL.path;
                if([manager fileExistsAtPath:path])
                {
                    NSError *attributesError = nil;
                    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&attributesError];
                    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
                    long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
                    if(fileSize > 0)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Recording finished with error, but trying to save whatever recorded");
                        // save whatever we have to camera roll.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```